What is the correct $\phi$ map in the following definition for the directed limit of the directed system of groups?
Background:
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 4:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 5:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,
if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their iimages in $G_k$.
Questions:
In continuation of this post.  I would like to ask
In Definition 5 2. where it says "there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi: G\to G'$", should the correct $\phi$ map be: $\phi: G'\to G$?
Thank you in advance

Where are you copying all these things from? You are clearly quoting, but you seem to want to keep the source a mystery for some strange reason.

@ArturoMagidin the book I got it from is:  A Graduate Course In Algebra, - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz.  I will edit all my previous posts accordingly.

Direct limits are initial objects, so $\phi$ is correct. The error is in the equation. It should be $\phi_i'=\phi\circ\phi_i$. Given apparent large preponderance of typos you seem to require help with, I would posit that your source was poorly edited a d should perhaps be replaced with something more reliable.

@ArturoMagidin I think the two authors did not expect the reader to know any category theory to understand the definitions.  I think they were trying to do the same as what Dummit & Foote did when the questions of direct and inverse limits were introduced in the context of rings.  I am still new to direct and inverse limits that is why I am asking on here because I know there are typos when I tried to work out the definitions.  I just could not figure out what the proper corrections are.

My point is that the quotes you have provided include many typos and errors. It's not because they don't expect the reader to know category theory, it's because it's carelessly edited. The equation you quote does not make sense, since $\phi_i'$ has codomain $G'$ and $\phi$ is written with domain $G$, so $\phi\circ \phi_i'$ doesn't work. The authors presumably know basic math and if they had properly proofread this, they would know there is something wrong. I am not criticizing that they don't invoke categories, I am criticizing that your quotes suggest the book is plagued w/typos

And a mathematical book plagued with typos in the equations isn't worth much. That has nothing to do with what the authors may be trying to do or the level of exposition.

@ArturoMagidin by the way, if it is not too much trouble, in $1.$ above, is it $i<j$ or $i\preceq j$?

The latter. Another careless error.

@ArturoMagidin ah okay okay.  Thank you.
